# What common task can I try to tackle/solve with various programming languages?

Tags: functional-programming, theory, computation-theory

I am looking for a problem to solve which enables me to try out various programming languages and having a means to compare the pros & cons of them. This is similar to [ToDoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) which does the same task with various MVC frameworks.
[Lisp 99 Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html) looks pretty good but am looking for interesting suggestions that might take on a real world problem and be a touch less mathematical. Failing that, I might tackle a few of these anyway.

Programming languages I'm looking to try this with:

- Haskell
- Clojure
- Javascript
- Erlang
- Scala
- Elm

Comment: Common tasks to solve? Your daily job

Comment: Have you looked at https://projecteuler.net/ The problems are mathematical though and require algorithmic knowledge too

Comment: Yes I have seen Project Euler. I may just try a few of those problems first and see how I go.